# Nginx rewrite and - char in domain name

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have domain name which contains - char. For example my-domain.com. When I use rewrite, Nginx rewrites url wrongly, browser is redirected to my.com instead of my-domain.com. What is wrong in my rewrite rule?

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name     www.my-domain.com;
    rewrite     ^/(.*) https://www.my-domain.com permanent;
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with what you have, above. I tested it with a CentOS 6.2 VM running nginx 1.0.13 and 1.2.0 using curl (`curl --header "Host:www.my-domain.com" --head 127.0.0.1`) and got the expected lines:  `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` and `Location: https://www.my-domain.com`. Your problem lies elsewhere. (the dash does need to be escaped (i.e. `\-`) when used in a regular expression - however, neither your server_name nor your rewrite destination are regexes). (Also, you can simplify your rewrite to use `^` instead of `^/(.*)` if you aren't using the capture.)

Comment: Its very odd, firefox is redirecting to wrong url, but not other browsers. Is firefox caching permanent redirects?

Comment: Start with Ctrl+F5, then if that doesn't work, clear your Firefox cache and restart Firefox, use private browsing mode, and check the Location header with Firebug. Keep in mind, it is a 'permanent' redirect, so it should be cached by the browser/ intermediate proxies. You may also want to change the destination of your rewrite (e.g. www1 or /test1, etc) so that you can verify that you aren't loading a cached redirect.

Comment: It was firefox's cache, I had tried some other settings before and apparently those had something wrong settings and those redirects were cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the server block you have used.

I tested the exact block you provided, with a CentOS 6.2 Virtual Machine running nginx 1.0.13 and nginx 1.2.0. I used curl to provide the matching Host header:

```
curl --header "Host:www.my-domain.com" --head 127.0.0.1
```

The response showed no error, successfully pointing to the new destination (note the 'Location' header):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.0
Date: Sun, 29 Apr 2012 18:56:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.my-domain.com
```

It is worth noting that the dash is a special character in regular expressions, and as a result, does need to be escaped (i.e. `\-`) when used in a regex. In your server block, however, neither your server_name nor your rewrite destination are regexes (although, it is possible for a server_name to be a regex).

As an aside, if you aren't using the capture, you can simplify your rewrite to:

```
rewrite     ^ https://www.my-domain.com permanent;
```

It is quite probable that your redirect has been cached by your browser (it is a 'permanent' redirect, so it could be cached by the browser/ intermediate proxies). Some suggestions for dealing with that may include:

- Force a refresh with: Ctrl+F5
- Clear your browser cache and restart the browser
- Use private browsing mode
- Check the Location header with your developer tools (e.g. Firebug)
- Flush your DNS cache

When testing such configurations, you may want to make a visible change with each modification (e.g. www1 or /test1, etc) so that you can verify that you aren't loading cached content.